# Selenium StaleElementReferenceException on ajax option select

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, jsf-2.2

I´m testing a form with 4 selects . When I select the first one it makes an ajax call depending on the value and populates the next select . But most of the time I´m getting a StaleElementReferenceException . I´m implementing FluentWait and my custom Expected condition to test that the select is populated

I´m using the same FluentWait

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(webdriver).withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

Here is the code that retrieves the webelement , and select the 3rd element.

```
        WebElement brand= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("brand")));
        Select selectBrand= new Select(brand);
        wait.until(new SelectCondition(selectBrand));           
        marcaSelect.selectByIndex(2);


        WebElement model= wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("model")));
        Select modelSelect = new Select(model);
        wait.until(new SelectCondition(modelSelect));
        modeloSelect.selectByIndex(2);
```

My custom expected conditions

```
class SelectCondition implements ExpectedCondition{

        Select select ;

        public SelectCondition(Select select){
            this.select = select;
        }

        public Boolean apply(Object arg0) {
            return  this.select.getOptions().size() > 1 ;
        }

    }
```

Im testing with selenium webdriver 3.3.1 , jsf 2.2 , java 1.7 , chrome , eclipse

Comment: Which particular line gives you StaleEelementException?

Comment: return  this.select.getOptions().size() > 1 ;

Answer (score 0):

```
// Below method will wait till value you are expecting is displayed in dropdown
public void waitForDropDownToLoad(final By by, final String sVal,
        String iSecs) {
    try {

        Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(getDriver())
                .withTimeout(Integer.parseInt(iSecs), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .pollingEvery(
                        Integer.parseInt(configProperties
                                .getProperty("sPollingTime")),
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                Select select = new Select(getDriver().findElement(by));
                List<WebElement> options = select.getOptions();
                for (WebElement option : options) {
                    if (option.getText().equals(sVal)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return null;

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("Exception in waitForDropDownToLoad()" + e);
    }
}

//Now try below code
 WebElement brand= 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("brand")));

 //Wait for option to be loaded in dropdown
 waitForDropDownToLoad(By.id("brand"), "OptionText", "10")

 // Select option in dropdown
 Select selectBrand= new Select(brand);
 selectBrand.selectByVisibleText("OptionText");

 // Get webelement
 WebElement model= 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("model")));

 //Wait for option to be loaded in dropdown
 waitForDropDownToLoad(By.id("model"), "ModelOption", "10")

 //Select option 
 Select modelSelect = new Select(model);
 modeloSelect.selectByVisibleText("ModelOption");
```

Comment: I used this approach but still having StaleReferenceException on Select element = new Select(element);